# How to stop os.walk from walking all sub-directories down?

Tags: python

Using:

```
def simpleFunc(dirName):
    import os
    fileList=[]
    for dir, dirs, filenames in os.walk(dirName):
        for filename in filenames:
            filepath=dir+'/'+filename
            fileList.append(filepath)
    print fileList


simpleFunc(os.path.dirname('/entire/path/to/file.ext'))
```

The problem is that `os.walk` just doesn't stop at `/entire/path/to/` directory level but goes all the way down to the lowest sub-directory it can find. So if there is `/entire/path/to/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3` then in additional to `/entire/path/to/` all three sub-directories will be searched: `./subdir1/`, `././subdir2/`, `./././subdir3/`.
Question: how to make sure the function stops at the directory level specified: `/entire/path/to/` and doesn't go all the way down?

Comment: so u want append filepath only in the directory /entire/path/to/ not its sub directories am i correct?

Comment: Yes, I only want to search for the files in `/entire/path/to/` directory and no where else.

Comment: if any of the answer fulfilled the requirement . please tick the right answer .that helps other user too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've written, if you just want to search the specified directory. It might be better to use `os.listdir` and then just filter on `os.path.isfile`, e.g., like this:

```
def simple_func(dirpath):
    paths = os.listdir(dirpath)
    # create absolute paths
    abs_paths = [os.path.join(dirpath, p) for p in paths]
    # filter for paths that are files
    file_list = [p for p in paths if os.path.isfile(p)]
    return file_list
```

That way you don't have to deal with stopping the recursion and it's pretty clear which files you want. You might want to profile to see whether the multiple `isfile` calls hurt anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
path='/entire/path/to/'
files = [ join(path,f) for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path,f)) ]
```

files return ur files. no need to declare new filelist

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should use `os.listdir` instead.

```
import os

my_path = '/entire/path/to/files/'
file_list = []
for filename in os.listdir(my_path):
  filepath = os.path.join(my_path, filename)
  if os.path.isfile(filepath):
    fileList.append(filepath)
```

Comment: i am not critising u. but  what is difference between above answer and urs . both are same. why do we need to reapeat it :)

Comment: Ah, you must've answered right before I submitted my answer. Sorry didn't see yours earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the only first item from the `os.walk` generator:

```
import os

root, _, files = next(os.walk('/entire/path/to'))
```

and then append root dir to each filename:

```
files = map(lambda f: os.path.join(root, f), files)
```

or just:

```
files = [os.path.join(root, f) for f in files]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell os.walk which directory to use explicitly

```
def simpleFunc(dirName):
    import os

    # set the dir name in a var
    dirName = '/higher_lever_dir/'

    for dir, dirs, filenames in os.walk(dirName):

        # this line forces loop to look ONLY in the specified dir
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d in dirName]

        for filename in filenames:
            filepath=dir+'/'+filename
            fileList.append(filepath)
    print fileList


simpleFunc(os.path.dirname('/entire/path/to/file.ext'))
```

Setting dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d in dirName] will exclude files in subdirectories that may exist in /higher_level_dir/